# How to see what browser (and version) a user is using?

Tags: php, javascript, cross-browser

Due to the CSS3 and HTML5, I would like to check what browser (and version) the visitor is using. What is the best way of doing that? I know that most ways screw up certain checks, for example phones or tablets, as well as some uncommon browsers, but there ought to be a way to get that information properly?

Comment: The best way rather than checking browser type, is to make feature check in order to see which features the browser is supporting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). It's a js library that does what you need

Answer (score 1):

No need to have JS libraries or other included files!

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo $browser['browser'];
```

This will return something like "Firefox," "Opera," "Safari," etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP for this

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

OR you can use google analytic to view live data of your visitor